# Angular 6 app shows error 'ERROR TypeError: t.merge is not a function' on production server

Tags: angular, typescript

I made an Angular 6 app which works well on development server but when i use 'ng build --prod' and throw it on a server , it shows error when i click on login and navigate to sidebar component.

If you need any more code , just comment.

on login click , this function is called in logincomponent.ts:

```
onLoginSubmit(f: NgForm) {
this.api.loginUser({'email': f.value['email'], 'password': f.value['password']})
  .subscribe(
    result => {
        this.api.xAuthToken = result.headers.get('x-auth-token');
        const expireDate = new Date();
        expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
        this._cookie.put('xAuth', this.api.xAuthToken, {'expires': expireDate});
        this.onProfileReady();
    },
    err => {
      this.errList = err.error.message;
      this.wrong = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.wrong = false;
      }, 5000);
    }
  );
  }

onProfileReady() {
    this.api.getprofile().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.api.user = response.body;
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      },
    (error) => { }
    );
  }
```

after login is successful, sidebarcomponent is loaded (which is not loading in production server)

[image]

Comment: Your stacktrace is from a production build with minified/uglified code. Please update your question with a dev build stacktrace if possible.

Comment: can you tell how to do that ? (never heard of it :( )

Comment: Seems it has something to do with `CookieOptions`